# Java - array not working inside the loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to get my loop to go through the array 16 times. When I use upCollisions[i], it doesn't work but when I use upCollisions[0] or any other index of the array, it works. I can't understand why it is not working using the for loop.

Here's my code:

```
public void handleUpArrow()
{
    int upCollisions[] = {15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0,};
    for(int i =0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if(goldenBallPosition == upCollisions[i])
        {
        }
        else
        {
            jBGrid[goldenBallPosition].setIcon(imageSand);
            jBGrid[goldenBallPosition -16].setIcon(imageBall);
            goldenBallPosition -= 16;
            jBCompass.setIcon(imageCompassNorth);
            jTDirection.setText("N");
            jTSquare.setText((""+goldenBallPosition));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem - explaining *exactly* what you mean by "it doesn't work".

Comment: Remove the last comma in the array. There is one too many at the end.

Comment: You should put the if condition as a NOT condition and then put the code within that if instead of having an empty if and the code in the else. It will have the same effect and be much cleaner

Comment: Also where is goldenBallPosition being initialized?

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code. First of all it's better to make the work in the `if` branch, and not in the `else`. Then I think the problem could be in this line of code:

```
goldenBallPosition -=16;
```

If I do undestand correctly your code, it could help if you use a loop like this

```
for (int i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
```

Don't you receive an `ArrayOutOfBoundException` during execution?

Comment: How `goldenBallPosition` is initialized? I think this is the core of the problem.

Comment: @Callum At what line does the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occur?